# Setting long expiration time for the oauth2 access and refresh tokens using golang

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api, refresh-token

I have used oauth2 package Config.Exchange function to get the token after syncing my account. But for the first time sync it returns me a expiration time for the token of 7 days from the time of sync. And for the next token exchange, it's returning expiry time of 24hours. I want to set a longer period expiration.

I went through then oauth2 package documentation, found this: https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/antipatterns/oauth-long-expiration#antipattern, but couldn't get to know the procedure to handle in Golang code.

Any ideas? please suggest.

Comment: Token expiration is set by the authorization server this is not something you can control.

Comment: I have found this but didn't get any package or function to use such scenario.



<OAuthV2 name="GenerateAccessToken">
    <Operation>GenerateAccessToken</Operation>
    <ExpiresIn>1800000</ExpiresIn> <!-- 30 minutes -->
    <RefreshTokenExpiresIn>17280000000</RefreshTokenExpiresIn> <!-- 200 days -->
    <SupportedGrantTypes>
      <GrantType>password</GrantType>
    </SupportedGrantTypes>
    <GenerateResponse enabled="true"/>
</OAuthV2>

Answer (score 0):

Rather than thinking about increasing the expiration time for a token you can instead use the [`Refresh token`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) you have to consider the following expiration time frames and reasons when using a refresh token:

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.
>
> There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per Google Account per OAuth 2.0 client ID. If the limit is reached, creating a new refresh token automatically invalidates the oldest refresh token without warning. This limit does not apply to service accounts.

In this case the documentation states that `You must write your code to anticipate the possibility that a granted refresh token might no longer work` so it would be a good idea to apply this on your code.

Comment: I am using refresh token to regenerate the accesstoken. But the expiration time for accesstoken is reduces to 1hour. So I need to set the expiration time for both.

Comment: The AccessToken and RefreshToken expiration can't be modified it is received as a response from the [Google Cloud's Security Token Service API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/sts/rest/v1/TopLevel/token#response-body) you may want to check again this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#size)